# Processing local components with vue

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code:

```
<my-messages>
    <message>Hello</message>
    <message>World</message>
</my-messages>
```

For now, I did my `<my-messages>` component be renderized as:

```
<div class="Messages">
    <!-- slot here -->
</div>
```

And I like to do the same for `<message>`, but the problem is that I receiving the error `Unknown custom element: <message>`. Except if I change my code to:

```
<my-messages inline-template>
    <message>Hello</message>
</my-messages>
```

It seems a bit hack, once that I should declare the `[inline-template]` to all `<my-messages>` components, instead of it be treated directly from this component as a default rule (eg. an option as `inlineTemplate: true` should do the work, if it exists).

The expected render should be like:

```
<div class="Messages">
    <div class="message">Hello</div>
    <div class="message">World</div>
</div>
```

---

My component currently:

```
export default {
    components: {
        // Should process <message> sub-component.
        message: require('./Messages.Message.vue'),
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**: on reality, the `inline-template` seems mixing both `<div>`s from template, and not nesting it.

Comment: Is that component code (`export default...`) your `my-messages` component?

Comment: Yes, it is. It is a snippet from my code: https://pastebin.com/drYfWGwX

Answer (score 1):

`inline-template` is not a hack. I think The problem is you're not registering `message` components at the same place where you're using `my-messages` component.

So the parent component that has `my-messages` as a child can't understand `message`, you need to register it in the parent too, when you use `inline-template` the scope changes and and whatever is inside will be treated as inner content. You can find it in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates)

**EDIT**

There isn't a way to have `<message>` to be only usable as a child of `<my-messages>`, you could however throw an exception if it's misused

```
mounted() {
  if (!this.$parent.$el.classList.contains('my-message')) {
    this.$destroy();
    throw new Error('You must wrap the message in a my-message');
  }
}
```

Note that this supposes that the class `my-message` is available in the root element, this way you can use any wrapper element.

Comment: Right... But if I do `Vue.component('messages', ...)` it will not be declared globally inside my instance? I like that `<message>` be available only inside `<my-messages>` (as a `<option>` to a `<select>`, for instance).

Comment: @DavidRodrigues no unfortunately you can't. I edited the answer with a way to throw an error if it's not used how you intend it to be